# How can I tell if I'm in a tmux session from a bash script?

Tags: bash, prompt, tmux

I like to keep my `bash_profile` in a [git repository](https://github.com/brantb/dotfiles) and clone it to whatever machines I have shell access to. Since I'm in `tmux` most of the time I have a `user@host` string in the status line, rather than its traditional spot in the shell prompt.

Not all sites I use have `tmux` installed, though, or I may not always be using it. I'd like  to detect when I'm not in a `tmux` session and adjust my prompt accordingly. So far my half-baked solution in `.bash_profile` looks something like this:

```
_display_host_unless_in_tmux_session() {
    # ???
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=$(_display_host_unless_in_tmux_session)${REST_OF_PROMPT}'
```

(Checking every time probably isn't the best approach, so I'm open to suggestions for a better way of doing this. Bash scripting is not my forte.)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Tmux sets the `TMUX` environment variable in tmux sessions, and sets `TERM` to `screen`. This isn't a 100% reliable indicator (for example, you can't easily tell if you're running `screen` inside `tmux` or `tmux` inside `screen`), but it should be good enough in practice.

```
if ! { [ "$TERM" = "screen" ] && [ -n "$TMUX" ]; } then
  PS1="@$HOSTNAME $PS1"
fi
```

If you need to integrate that in a complex prompt set via `PROMPT_COMMAND` (which is a bash setting, by the way, so shouldn't be exported):

```
if [ "$TERM" = "screen" ] && [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
  PS1_HOSTNAME=
else
  PS1_HOSTNAME="@$HOSTNAME"
fi
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="$PS1_HOSTNAME…"'
```

If you ever need to test whether tmux is installed:

```
if type tmux >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  # you can start tmux if you want
fi
```

By the way, this should all go into `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.bash_profile` (see [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980)). `~/.bashrc` is run in every bash instance and contains shell customizations such as prompts and aliases. `~/.bash_profile` is run when you log in (if your login shell is bash). Oddly, bash doesn't read `~/.bashrc` in login shells, so your `~/.bash_profile` should contain

```
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

Comment: There is an alternative variable `TMUX_PANE` as well. I only noticed because your recipe didn't work. Later I found out that I had unduly used (and subsequently `unset`) a variable in a shell script I am sourcing through my `.profile`.

Comment: `[ "$TERM" = "screen" ]` may not work. In my case, my screen was reporting as `screen-256` color.

Comment: @StevieD I don't think tmux does this on its own, but it might be a distribution patch or configuration.

Comment: $TMUX and $TMUX_PANE don't mean "in a tmux session", they just mean they exist, if you run a terminal running with tmux, open another terminal running without tmux, check their values in second terminal, they still exist.

Comment: My `TERM` var is a reflection of what's in my `tmux` config. In my case `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"`, so `TERM=tmux-256color` is what is set in my env.

Comment: `tmux` and `tmux-256color` has been added to terminfo. Nowadays `$TERM` in tmux should be one of these two, not `screen`, [not `screen-256color`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745718/108618). Still one can use something else with tmux command `set -g default-terminal …`.

Answer (score 7):

As for previous answers, testing the `${TERM}` variable could lead to corner cases, `tmux` sets environment variables within its own life:

```
$ env|grep -i tmux
TMUX=/tmp/tmux-1000/default,4199,5
TMUX_PANE=%9
TMUX_PLUGIN_MANAGER_PATH=/home/imil/.tmux/plugins/
```

In order to check if you're inside a `tmux` environment, simply check:

`$ [ -z "${TMUX}" ] && echo "not in tmux"`

Answer (score 7):

If you're running `tmux` release 3.2 or later (or using [OpenBSD 6.8 or later](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/tmux/environ.c?rev=1.25&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup), or built `tmux` from sources [newer than May 16 2020](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/4e053685df9f4d1c398148712ab0529a7e9d32e7)), you may use the `TERM_PROGRAM` environment variable.

```
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = tmux ]; then
  echo 'In tmux'
else
  echo 'Not in tmux'
fi
```

Earlier releases of `tmux` does not have this environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

After trying different ways, this is what ultimately worked for me, in case it helps anyone out there:

```
if [[ "$TERM" =~ "screen".* ]]; then
  echo "We are in TMUX!"
else
  echo "We are not in TMUX :/  Let's get in!"
  # Launches tmux in a session called 'base'.
  tmux attach -t base || tmux new -s base
fi
```

In this code snippet, I check to see if we're not in TMUX environment, I launch it. If you put this code snippet in your `.bashrc` file, you will automatically run TMUX anytime you open terminal!
P.S.: tested on Ubuntu shell.

Comment: Wouldn't this code also think we're in `tmux` if we were using GNU `screen`?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may not have access to `$TMUX`, and `$TERM` is certainly not reliable. Then, you can compare window ids: the one obtained from `tmux` itself, and the one you can get from `xdotool`:

```
if [ $(tmux showenv | awk -v FS='=' '/WINDOWID/{print $2}') \
     -eq \
     $(xdotool getactivewindow) ]
then
    echo "This terminal is running tmux!"
fi
```