# Finding out whether current alias/function/script is running inside Tmux - with a twist

Tags: tmux

**NB:** Yes, I've read [How can I tell if I'm in a tmux session from a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10689)

How can I find out whether I am running inside a Tmux session from my shell or shell script or shell function or alias if I used `sudo su -` in between?:

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 3):

In your `/etc/sudoers` file you can explicitly allow environment variables to propagate to the sudo environment.

#### Example

```
Defaults    requiretty

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
```

So one method would be to add a variable that is resultant of `tmux` and let it through.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that's one way (btw: one I know and had contemplated). And in this particular case I am able to modify `sudoers`, but I'll leave the question open to see whether some better method exists.

Comment: That'll work for `sudo -s` but not for `sudo su -` since `su -` also resets the environment. Not that there's usually a good reason to run `su -` instead of keeping as much information about your environment as you can @0xC0000022L

Answer (score 2):

```
% sudo su -- 2<<STATE
>    TMUX='$TMUX'
>    exec 2>/dev/tty 
> STATE
# . /dev/fd/2
# { 
#   echo "$TMUX"
#   echo "$TMUX" >&2
# }

###OUTPUT

/tmp/tmux-1000/default,23878,1
/tmp/tmux-1000/default,23878,1
```

`sudo` will close all file descriptors for its invoked process but `0,1,2` and you need `/dev/tty` on `<&0` or you can't enter a password, but if you can accept blocking `>&2` for the span it takes to run a single command then you can do the above.

You can use this technique to bring along whatever else you might like as well.

Comment: Nice, I need to check how well this works in case of unprivileged users running a `Cmnd_Alias`, but certainly a very interesting piece of info!

Comment: @0xC0000022L - it works pretty well. It can be controlled with permissions, but one thing about `.dot` is it doesn't `exec` anything - it only requires read rights. So even when `su 4<<HEREDOC /dev/fd/4\n...\nHEREDOC\n` doesn't work `su -c '. /dev/fd/4' 4<<..` generally will.

Comment: That's not very convenient for an interactive session though. However, you could do something like `exec $SHELL 2>/dev/tty`

Comment: @Gilles - thanks for that. It took me a minute to figure out what you meant because I thought the shell would automatically reopen `>&2` but I was wrong. You likely can't `exec` it with a new process like that though without `chown`ing the file created by your last user first, but just `exec 2>/dev/tty` seems to do the trick anyway. I did it but added an `>&2` to `echo` as above and it   worked.