# Running script through bashrc causes nesting of tmux panes

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, tmux, bashrc

I use the following tmux code in a script file `tmux-dev.sh` and add it to bash using `bash /home/rohit/tmux-dev.sh` :

```
tmux new-session -d
tmux split-window -h
tmux split-window -v
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

The script causes a nesting of tmux panes giving error: pane too small.
To my surprise , the same `bash tmux-dev.sh` when put into the `title and command` box of gnome-terminal it works perfectly fine and gives this screen
[image: screenshot]

Please help me out with this.I am using ubuntu 14.10.

**P.S--** Please stay away from suggesting any tools , I am here for an explanation for this behavior and raw shell script solution.

Comment: So you add it to `bashrc`. I'm not experienced with `tmux`, but might it be that every new session starts its own bash shell and thus calls `.bashrc` again making it basically an endless loop?

Comment: @Fiximan Exactly ! each session starts its own bash shell and that's why its happening . How can I have that above tmux setting( 3 window panes ) without it to cause an endless loop.

Comment: you could change your `bashrc` to check if you are NOT in a `tmux` session before running the script: `if [ ! tmux session ] ; then bash tmux-dev.sh ; fi `. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10689/how-can-i-tell-if-im-in-a-tmux-session-from-a-bash-script) for an example check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fiximan suggested , I tried to test if tmux session exists or not and then execute some code and finally, with a little tweak I am successful in getting the layout I wanted. Here is what I added to my `.bashrc` :

```
test -z "$TMUX" && (tmux new-session -d && tmux split-window -h && tmux split-window -v && tmux -2 attach-session -d)
```

I will break down the above for an explanation:

1. `test -z "$TMUX"` **->** This tests whether there is already a tmux session running or not , thus, preventing nesting of tmux sessions
2. `tmux new-session -d` **->** Creates a new session
3. `tmux split-window -h` **->** Splits the window vertically
4. `tmux split-window -v` **->** Splits the window horizontally
5. `tmux -2 attach-session -d`**->** Attaches the sessions

**NOTE--** I have used `&&` operator not the `||` operator because the later would short-circuit.