# Getting italics working correctly in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, colors

I have an issue that the colors and font don't get produced correctly in tmux. The same output looks different when the command is run outside vs inside tmux.

Outside tmux:

[image]

Inside tmux:

[image]

As suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux), I have `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in my `.tmux.conf`. The output of `tput` and `$TERM` are correct as well.

```
$ tput colors
256

$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside tmux, the program that produced the output on your screenshots "thinks" the terminal does not support italic mode. The program does not try to use italics, it chooses to manipulate background color instead.

This is because `screen-256color` you specified apparently does not support italic mode. There's a way to confirm this. In my Kubuntu the following command

```
TERM=screen-256color infocmp -1 | grep -E 'ritm|sitm'
```

produces empty output (no support), while

```
TERM=tmux-256color infocmp -1 | grep -E 'ritm|sitm'
```

gives us escape sequences to enter (`sitm`) or exit (`ritm`) italic mode (see `man 5 terminfo`).

Any program that queries the terminfo database will see that `screen-256color` does not support italic mode. To convince programs that your terminal does support it, you need to choose something with the support.

Hopefully your terminfo database contains `tmux-256color`. This is the right value of `$TERM` for you. **Solution:** use `tmux-256color` instead of `screen-256color`.

Comment: Appreciate the clear explanation, I recognize the strange edge case here and everything makes sense :)

Comment: `TERM=screen-256color` is for the `screen` command. `TERM=tmux=256color` is for the `tmux` command

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! In my case, this was somehow set by iTerm2 (Profiles->Default->Terminal -> Report terminal type) and I had to change it there as well as in my `.tmux.conf`